# How to track down source of "Missing or insufficient permissions" in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**NOTE:** This question is not about how to resolve any particular "Missing or insufficient permissions" Firestore error. This question is about tracking down the source of the error. Every other question on S.O. that I've been able to find that references this error in Firestore is asking a different question, so please read through the entire question and check creation dates on any other questions you find before you try to mark this as a duplicate.

**tl;dr:** Is there a good way to track down either the location in code that triggers this error ***or*** the specific security rule that is being violated?

When the Firebase library throws this error it doesn't provide any information about where in the code this error is being throw or which security rule is being violated (which is probably a good thing, since in the wild, providing this information could make it easier for a hacker to do something nefarious). However, in development, it makes things difficult to debug. If I'm working on a particular query, it's usually not a problem, because when I make a change and see this error, I know the code I was just working on is causing the error. But there are other circumstances where the source is less obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to use the Firebase security rules emulator. It will show you what's happening during rule evaluation. Other than this, there are currently no diagnostics to help you understand what's happening with security rules deployed to your project when invoked from client code.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: This sounds great, except I can't for the life of me get the instructions on the referenced page to work. Installing the emulator seems to work fine and then running it fails with this message: `Error: emulators:start is not a Firebase command`. (I'm running it inside a directory with `firebase.json` and have the latest Firebase CLI installed.)

Comment: If you're having problems with the emulator, please make sure your CLI is fully up to date, then post an issue on its GitHub with repro instructions. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools