# How to debug Firestore security rules in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing my first app in Flutter and got stuck with the Firestore security rules. I can allow write & read and everything works fine, but if I want to limit adding of objects to users who have an account, things break.

More specifcally I have the following rules:

```
    match /ratings/{anyRatingFile=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data.user)).id;
    }
```

Basically, if the user ID from the request exists, then I will accept the creating request. I can use the online simulator and it works! If the UID is not registered I get rejected and otherwise the request is accepted. But when I try to create an object in my flutter App, it always crashes with the following stack trace:

```
W/Firestore(30727): (19.0.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at ratings/48MZwRY66G13g8T0Nl8j: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter (30727): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing setData, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)
E/flutter (30727): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter (30727): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:316:33)
E/flutter (30727): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30727): #2      DocumentReference.setData (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:51:30)
E/flutter (30727): #3      CollectionReference.add (package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart:58:23)
E/flutter (30727): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30727): #4      MyApp.submitRating (package:MyApp/screens/myscreen.dart:128:16)
E/flutter (30727): #5      MyApp._buildMain.<anonymous closure> (package:MyApp/screens/myscreen.dart:93:24)
E/flutter (30727): #6      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
E/flutter (30727): #7      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:711:32)
E/flutter (30727): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (30727): #9      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
E/flutter (30727): #10     TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
E/flutter (30727): #11     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:455:9)
E/flutter (30727): #12     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:75:13)
E/flutter (30727): #13     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:102:11)
E/flutter (30727): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (30727): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (30727): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (30727): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (30727): #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (30727): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (30727): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (30727): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (30727): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:250:10)
E/flutter (30727): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:159:5)
```

and per request, here is the code:

```
  var collection = Firestore.instance.collection('ratings');

    collection.add({
      "puzzle": "/sample/" + ID,
      "user": "/users/" + appState.user.uid,
      "rating": rating,
    });
```

And a bit more debug info. This request on the firestore website works, e.g. return "Simulated write allowed".

```
{"__name__":"/databases/(default)/documents/ratings/test","id":"test","data":{"user":"/users/PCAE2"}}
```

Authentication Payload:

```
{
  "uid": "PCAE2",
  "token": {
    "sub": "PCAE2",
    "aud": "myApp-1",
    "email": "",
    "email_verified": false,
    "phone_number": "",
    "name": "",
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I cut out most of the user ID for anonymity, but otherwise it is a copy-paste. And in my local log I see the following message:

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(30727): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@9304ffb
D/FirebaseAuth(30727): Notifying id token listeners about user ( PCAE2 ).
I/flutter (30727): Logged in
```

So two questions:

1) What is the issue here?

2) How do I debug this sort of errors? I tried to find some Firestore log files, but couldn't find any. I can see that I can write unit tests, but the test on the website doesn't help because it passes.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that performs the query that doesn't work the way you expect.  Rules don't mean much unless they're paired with a query that the rule is supposed to allow or deny.

Comment: Your rules are requiring that a user is signed in, and the contents of a document have certain values.  Please edit the question to include all of the relevant details.  We can't see into your database, nor see the UID of the user.  It might be good to say why you think this rule should allow the document to be added.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson for the help, I added more info to the question.

Comment: And the contents of the document being read in the rule, as it relates to the **actual** uid of the user making the request in the app, not in the console simulator?  Does the added document property `user` actually match the read document's id property?  That's is what your rule is requiring - please verify all the requirements are actually being met by the app.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if you can use a path component with a slash (e.g. /users/foo) when building a path to a document in rules using the syntax you have now.  You might have to build a string to the document, then convert that to a path using `path(string)`, then pass that to get().

Comment: If I use get(path(/...)) then the simulation tells me  Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [get], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"] - can you tell me how I can check if the other requirements are met? I am using android studio, should I tell the debugger to stop at the .add call?

Comment: If you want to debug your rules, your only option is to use the local emulator.  The console simulator is not at all complete.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57938882/how-to-track-down-source-of-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-in-firestore/57939017

Comment: I stepped into a debugger, but I don't know what to do. I get a call to "Future<DocumentReference> add(Map<String, dynamic> data) async" and I inspected the data object and it looks good (the user ID is correct). Not sure what to do next.
Edit: I tried to find the auth object and could not, I can only see my payload. Can I verify that this is present?

Comment: What is your intention with the rule? Do you just wnat to check the `data.user.id` to be equal to `userid`? If yes, why are you doing it like `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data.user)).id` why not `request.resource.data.user.id`? If not, top level objects of firestore are supposed to be collections. So the expression `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data.user)).id` is wrong. It should be `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users-or-something/$(request.resource.data.user)).id`

Comment: I want to find out if the request-id is valid, e.g. if the user exists in the database. And I am passing /users/ in the request, so that is why I didn't include it in the path. I can try without and see if that works. But the more general question is, how can I debug this in the future? I don't think this will be the last issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my particular problem, but I still don't know how to debug this in general. So if you know, please let me know.

The issue here was another rule:

```
match /users/{userId}/{anyUserFile=**} {
    allow read, write, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId
}
```

My mistake, that I did not include that in the question, but I assumed it would not have been a problem because the simulation works. Anyway, removing this line and allowing read & write for everybody in the world to the /users/ table fixes the problem.

This opens up a list of new questions though:

1. Why did the simulation work, but not my flutter App request?
2. How can I protect the /users/ table?
3. How do I debug things like this in the future, if the simulator differs from the app behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Firebase security rules cannot be debugged. But, surely you can validate the rules via a [simulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator)

**Example**

[image]

Comment: as I said in the question, the simulated write works as expected, it is only my flutter app that crashes.